# HTML table fit cell height to contents valign top

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables, styling

I am trying to create a table where the left column is pushed top to fit its contents. Note that the right column requires to be `height=300`.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td valign="top" width="65%">
    This is my 1st cell
  </td>
  <td valign="top"  width="35%" height="300" rowspan="3" align="right">
    This is long cell
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="65%">This is my 2nd cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="65%">
      This is my 3rd cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I have come out so far: https://jsfiddle.net/5y33rtm3/1/

[image]

Desired outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `rowspan="5"` for the third row in the left:

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="65%">
      This is my 1st cell
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="35%" height="300" rowspan="7" align="right">
      This is long cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="65%">This is my 2nd cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="65%" rowspan="5"> <!-- CHANGED HERE -->
      This is my 3rd cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or you can add `height: 100%` to it:

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="65%">
      This is my 1st cell
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="35%" height="300" rowspan="7" align="right">
      This is long cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="65%">This is my 2nd cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="65%" style="height: 100%"> <!-- CHANGED HERE --> 
      This is my 3rd cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi kukkuz, this works for text, but if my contents in the cells is an image, the 1st and 2nd cell overlaps each other since the image is too big. Is there a way to dynamically resize the contents of the cells based on its contents (fit cell height to contents).

Comment: ohh, then this should work: have added `rowspan`s... please check

Comment: was browsing through my old answers and enhanced the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td  width="65%">
    This is my 1st cell
  </td>
  <td valign="top"  width="35%" height="300" rowspan="3" align="right">
    This is long cell
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="65%">This is my 2nd cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="height:100%" width="65%">
      <img src="ant.jpg" style="height:40%;width:40%;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try out this in the third row. I get the output as you want